# XSS - Javascript String

Tags: javascript, string, xss

Is it possible to perform an XSS on the following:

```
<script> var name = "USER_INPUT";</script>
```

where USER_INPUT is given by the user. I have a filter for USER_INPUT which doesn’t accept <  and " characters but accepts &quot.
I do not use the variable name in the html and use it only for processing inside the script.

Comment: How is the input given? How is it processed?

Comment: Use a proven library that sanitizes user input.

Comment: @Xufox The input is given by the user. I use the variable to do some logic in the javascript.

Comment: @Darkrum Can you share me the payload? If XSS is possible.

Comment: @epascarello If it is possible, can you share me the payload?

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @ShatabdaMajumdar http://www.jsfuck.com

Comment: @epascarello Thanks. Since, " and < are not accepted by the filter. I could not find any payload that would work on this.

Comment: @Sha And again: _How_ is it given by the user? _What kind_ of logic are you doing with JavaScript? The answer entirely depends on how _precisely_ the input gets created and used.

Comment: @Xufox I use it to do some validation based on the name. For example: If the name starts with A --> Some action. If it starts with B --> Some action. The input is given by the user in the form that loads.

Comment: read more at https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/cross-site-scripting/

Comment: @Sha So then the answer is no. Getting an input from a form just produces a string, nothing more. Testing the string doesn’t make an attack possible. At least, if everything is done right, and if the browser doesn’t have any weird bugs, like JSON hijacking.

Comment: @Xufox OP's a lost cause. Wait till he finds out Sanitation client side is pointless as you can open up the console and do whatever you want and that sanitation needs to be done server side before storing. One might argue that sanitation client side is good just in case the server doesn't do it's job right... But at that point you have a major issue.

Comment: to be honest, I think the OP is not asking how to prevent XSS, he twice asked for possible XSS payload ... smells like script kiddie

Comment: @JaromandaX I am actually testing out if it is possible to break this.

Comment: yeah, I know, but the code you presented is just an input - surely any XSS issues come from what you do with the text that is input. And since you've shown zero actual code (html isn't code) can't see how you could get any worthwhile help at all

Answer (score 0):

I think it is important to check the best practices for sanitizing user input for the programming language that you are using.

For example for php you can check this question: [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Comment: I am sanitizing the input by filtering < and " characters. Is it still possible to perform XSS? Is there any payload for that?

Comment: Not on top of my head but I also came across a lot of other XSS types that I couldn't think of directly on https://xss-game.appspot.com/ So I cannot think something does not always mean there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

Under the restrictions you have mentioned there is no immediate risk of XSS. Make sure that any user input with `"` or `<` is denied (not just replaced) even better only accept whitelisted characters (e.g `[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]`). To make sure the variable `name` is not used for any dangerous processing (like db query) in the future better give it a recognizable name like `UNSAFE_name`  or something.

Answer (score 0):

If characters like backslashes, newlines, or html comment end tags are allowed, then they can at least break the formatting of the page or cause errors to be thrown, stopping the rest of the script from running.

There is also the risk of it easily becoming vulnerable if an extra variable is added. Like:

```
<script>var name = "USER_INPUT", name2 = "USER_INPUT2";</script>
```

Then, if `USER_INPUT` is `\`, and `USER_INPUT2` is `+alert(1)//` then this will run a script.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this payload:
`&qout; -alert(document.domain)- &quot;`

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you do with the variable `name`. If you are going to eval it, than the XSS is possible.

Supportingly, If the user input is `alert(1)` and you are going to eval it without curing its value. i.e.

```
eval(name);
```

Or if you are going to inject the `name` into the DOM the XSS is possible as well.

Have a look at the below example.

```
const first = 'Wes';
const User_input = `I love to do evil <img src="http://unsplash.it/100/100?random" onload="alert('you got hacked');" />`;

const html = `
    <h3>${first}</h3>
    <p>${User_input}</p>
`;

const bio = document.body;
bio.innerHTML = html;
```

But if you are properly sanitizing the user_input you can reduce the chances to XSS attack.

There are ways to sanitize the user_input. How are you sanitizing? Can you Show?

Comment: please read the question, OP said he is not embedding it into the html and refusing `<` characters

Comment: I use a regex to filter out the characters. All characters are allowed except " and <